# NoClassDefFoundError in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working with camera2 in Android Studio and when testing it I get a NoClassDefFoundError (runtime exception) on this line:
    `mCameraManager.openCamera("0", new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {`
I'm not sure what's causing this, but looking around at NoClassDefFoundError in general leads me to believe that it's caused when the static initialization code for a class (here, presumably CameraDevice.StateCallBack?) throws an exception. I'm wondering how I can fix this error. Do I need to initialize the CameraDevice.StateCallback in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is method got added in API level 21 (Lollipop). This means you are testing on a device that has an API lower than 21.

You can always check th [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#openCamera(java.lang.String,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)).

Comment: That makes a ridiculous amount of sense and I feel like an idiot, but does that mean that I should be creating 2 projects, one for Android L and one for everything else?

Comment: I don't know what this call supposed to do but if you have to use it and there is no other APIs that works on previous version and the Lollipop version as well. You can always check the android version at run time and have different implementations for different android versions. if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //Do something
} else { //Do something else }